# Create a link in SVG shown in Android Studio App

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

I show full screen SVGs in an WebView. Now I want to add a weblink in parts of the SVG so the user can tap on the content and the system browser opens and show the URL

with a browser on my PC it works (so the SVG is valid). I try xlink:href and href and it works

In Android i try

```
web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>body {margin:0px;} img {display:inline;}</style><img src=\"x.svg\">" , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

and

```
web_view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<style>body {margin:0px;} <object type=\"image/svg+xml\" data=\"x.svg"\"></object>" , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

both shows the SVG but the link is not working. any hint?